How to set dpi on jpeg image download?
$("#download-pdf-template").on("click", function(e) {  
    overallwidthcover = parseFloat(Number(overallwidthcover).toFixed(3));
    overallcoverhegiht = parseFloat(Number(overallcoverhegiht).toFixed(3));

    var covertype = $(this).data('id');
    var pdfWidthInInches = overallwidthcover ? overallwidthcover : 12.80;
    var pdfHeightInInches = overallcoverhegiht ? overallcoverhegiht : 9.25;


    var fileName;
    var htmlContent;

    if (Number(covertype) == 1) {
        htmlContent = '#paperpBackDownload';
        fileName = 'paper_back_cover_template.jpeg';
    } else {
        htmlContent = '#caseboundbackDownload';
        fileName = 'casebound_cover_template.jpeg';
    }

    var elementHTML = document.querySelector(htmlContent);
     // Desired DPI and dimensions
     var dpi = 300;
    
     var widthInPixels = pdfWidthInInches * 72;
     var heightInPixels = pdfHeightInInches * 72;

    html2canvas(elementHTML, {
        useCORS: true,
        // scale: 2  
        scale: dpi / 72
    }).then(function(canvas) {
        var adjustedCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        adjustedCanvas.width = widthInPixels;
        adjustedCanvas.height = heightInPixels;
        var ctx = adjustedCanvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, widthInPixels, heightInPixels);

        var imgData = adjustedCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0); // Convert to JPEG
       
        // Create a link element and simulate a click to download the image
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = imgData;
        link.download =  fileName;
        link.click();
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error capturing image:', error);
    });
});

I have an download button on clicking it will download an html content as jpeg. Everything seems fine but when i have open this image in pdf viewer then its dpi is 72 i want its dpi to be set as 300 how can i do that?

This question seems to be a duplicate
By the way, let's Google a bit o what does DPI stand for: DPI stands for Dots per Inch.
I fear that, since this is just a scanning setting/property for image acquisition, playing with height/width values won't change the image in terms of "resolution" during its download.

There is no provision in JPEG for DPI. There are various JPEG file formats that can incorporate DPI settings. There is no guarentee that your decoder will recognizes your file type or a specific setting within that file type.
In nearly all cases, JPEG decoder can ignore the file format and still render the image correctly.

shall we do it with imagick library of php ?? I tried using that but then its showing different dpi on different tools like photoshop and illustrator. Not sure which approach i can follow to show correct dimensions and dpi on image meta as well
